# I am using cakephp and want to know How to expire Session of admin

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, cakephp

I have written this code in UserController but unable to get result.whenever I Opened admin panel in two tab in the same browser and if logout from one tab then unable to redirect to login page from other tab when clicking on any menu.

```
function beforeFilter()
    {    
        if(($this->request->prefix)=='admin')
        $this->Auth->allow();
        $chk = $this->Session->check('Admin');
        $this->disableCache();
        if(@$this->Session->read('Admin') && ($this->request->action == 'admin_login'))
     {
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'dashboard','admin' => true));
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for logout action

```
    public function logout() {
        $this->Session->setFlash('you have successfully logged out');
        $this->Auth->logout();
        return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login'));
    }
```

In beforeFilter in appcontroller use this code

```
public function beforeFilter() {
   $this->Auth->loginAction = array('admin' => false, 'controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->logoutAction = array('admin' => false, 'controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'logout');
   $this->Auth->allow('index','login','forgot','changepass');

}
```

in controller use this beforeFilter function.

```
    public function beforeFilter() {

        parent::beforeFilter();

    }
```